# Whitespace character after backslash in C and C++

Tags: c++, c

What C and C++ standards says about whitespace character (or several characters) after backslash? Does it guarantees to join lines anyway or not?

```
int main()
{
    // Comment \ 
    int foo;
}
```

MSVC and gcc works different in this case.

Comment: In a C++ comment like this, everything up to the new line is the comment, so the backslash is included and does nothing. Also, in both languages whitespace is just whitespace, it doesn't matter if it is a space, newline, tab or whatever…

Comment: @sidyll: There are rules for the preprocessor, and in particular, if `\\` is immediately followed by new-line, it must be removed from the program, which means that, with no spaces after the backslash, the code in the question defines an empty `main`

Answer (score 7):

For reference, the standard quote is (§2.2/1, abridged, emphasis mine):

> ### Phases of Translation
>
> [...]
> 2. **Each instance of a backslash character (`\`) immediately followed by a new-line character is deleted, splicing physical source lines to form logical source lines**. Only the last backslash on any physical source line shall be eligible for being part of such a splice. If, as a result, a character sequence that matches the syntax of a universal-character-name is produced, the behavior is undefined. A source file that is not empty and that does not end in a new-line character, or that ends in a new-line character immediately preceded by a backslash character before any such splicing takes place, shall be processed as if an additional new-line character were appended to the file.
> [...]

The implementation-defined part that other answers are mentioning is in the definition of "new-line".

(Note that comments are not replaced until phase 3, so that in this code:

```
int main()
{
    int x = 0;

    // assuming the definition of new-line is as expected, this function
    // will return 0, not 5 (no whitespace after this backslash: ) \
    x = 5;

    return x;
}
```

`x = 5;` will be appended to the end of the comment, then ultimately removed.)

Answer (score 5):

The C standard leaves it implementation-defined how a text file is broken into lines (as part of translation phase 1, if memory serves).  For the purpose of `\`-newline, GCC defines a line ending as zero or more ASCII horizontal whitespace characters (SPC, TAB, VT, or FF) followed by one of the three common ASCII line termination sequences: CR, LF, or CR LF.

I do not know what MSVC does, but I would not be at all surprised if it is different.

Comment: Wow - I didn't know that GCC 'trimmed' whitespace at the end of a line before performing the splice check in translation phase 2. MSVC does not (so you're right about it being different).

Comment: GCC documents this behavior here: http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Initial-processing.html

Comment: BTW, backslash-newline is translation phase 3; phase 2 is trigraphs.

Comment: @Zach: I'm often impressed with the level of detail in the various gcc docs. In defense of my comment about phase 2, I'm going by what the C99 standard says (where trigraphs are lumped into phase 1). But, I wouldn't be surprised if the precise details of translation phases differ in other standards/docs/implementations (as long as they maintain the same order where that matters).

Comment: It's possible that I am misremembering.  It's been a long time.