# C++ single line comments followed by \ transforms in multiline comment

Tags: c++, c

Where is it documented in the C++ Standard the feature that if a line is commented using `//some comment\` style (at the end of the line puts `\`) the comment is transformed to multiline?

Tested with g++ 4.8 and VS 2012

```
//some interesting stuff\
another interesting stuff\
etc
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Whitespace character after backslash in C and C++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12305240/whitespace-character-after-backslash-in-c-and-c)

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor How is that a duplicate? The linked question asks about **whitespace after backslash** while this question asks about the backslash only.

Comment: @AlvinWong, I don't know, but apparently he got someone else to agree with him.

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor after 2 years of SO how comes that you don't know what is a duplicate question? When an answer from a question contains parts that are useful to another question it does not mean that the question is duplicate.

Comment: @AlvinWong The newline character *is* considered a whitespace character in C, so a question that asks how whitespace after a backslash is handled in C is more general than this one, and should include how one particular whitespace is handled in C.

Comment: @EmilCondrea As I mentioned to Alvin, newlines *are* whitespace characters, so a question that asks how whitespace after slashes in C are handled *should* contain an answer to the more specific question about one particular whitespace character.  As a more specific example, I think it'd make sense to at least consider "How is a newline after slash handled?" as a possible duplicate of "How are newlines and tabs after slash handled?"  That's a nice thing about the voting process here;  each voter can identify *possible* duplicates, but others still need to agree.

Comment: @PaulDraper The *possible* duplicate is about whitespace after backslash.  In C, the newline character is one of a number of whitespace characters. A question that asks "how are whitespace characters after a slash handled?" *should* contain an answer to "how is this one particular whitespace character after a slash handled?"

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor You seem to have misunderstood both questions. In this case, a newline is different from a whitespace. Read the answers below.

Comment: @AlvinWong I understand that all whitespace is not handled the same, and that slash+newline has a meaning and usage, whereas slash+other_whitespace doesn't.  My point is that an answer to "slash + whitespace" (the more general case) should cover both cases, explaining that "slash + whitespace" doesn't mean anything in general, but that the specific case of "slash + newline" does.

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor The linked question asks specificly about a whitespace (excluding newline). Try highlighting the code and you will see it.

Comment: @AlvinWong The code *example* in the other question uses a space after the slash;  I was aware of that when I voted.  The actual question, though, asks about "whitespace character (or several characters) after backslash?"  A given question can (usually) be exemplified by lots of different code snippets.  That one just happened to use "slash/space/newline".  Another could use "slash/tab/space/carriage-return/newline".  The important thing is that the question *asks* about the behavior of one or more whitespace characters after a slash.

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor The other question says "Does it guarantees to join lines anyway or not?" so the intentions are clear - the question is about whitespace characters different than newline.

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor My interpretation is that the linked question asks whether the backslash line continuation still works **when having an extra whitespace** before the newline, which is a different question.

Answer (score 93, accepted):

C++ standard, 2.2 - phases of translation. Phase 2 includes

> Each instance of a backslash character (`\`) immediately followed by a new-line character is deleted,
>   splicing physical source lines to form logical source lines.

and Phase 3 includes

> Each comment is replaced by one space character

So the backslash at the end of the line is recognised before comments.

Equivalent phases 2 and 3 for C can be found in C standard (5.1.1.2 Translation phases in my draft).

Comment: Who on earth down-voted this answer?  It's the most complete and correct (better than mine, for example).

Comment: How can this be useful if not confusing?

Comment: @DebugErr The *intent* was that on a system that imposed a hard upper limit on the length of physical source lines (e.g. punchcards) you could mechanically split every too-long line with \-newlines without having to parse the code.  I doubt this scenario has ever occurred in real life, but that was the original rationale.

Comment: backslash-newline is often used in long macro definitions.

Comment: Keep in mind that `//`-comments are relatively new to C-family languages, and in particular are *much* newer than the preprocessor. As with anything that evolves, there's conflicts that must be resolved, and the resolution isn't always the most elegant.

Answer (score 12):

A `\` followed by a new line is eliminated very early in the
translation process, before the compiler starts looking for
comments and the end of comments, see §2.2, Phases of
translation.

Answer (score 11):

Do you want to know for C or C++? (**EDIT:** In original question OP asked for C/C++)

For C following section from **ISO/IEC 9899:TC2 Committee Draft — May 6, 2005 WG14/N1124** answers your question.

**5.1.1.2 Translation phases**

> [2] Each instance of a backslash character () immediately followed by a
>   new-line character is deleted, splicing physical source lines to form
>   logical source lines. Only the last backslash on any physical source
>   line shall be eligible for being part of such a splice. A source file
>   that is not empty shall end in a new-line character, which shall not
>   be immediately preceded by a backslash character before any such
>   splicing takes place.

For C++, you can refer to [Phase 2 at en.cppreference.com](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/translation_phases)

> 1) Whenever backslash appears at the end of a line (immediately
>   followed by the newline character), both backslash and newline are
>   deleted, combining two physical source lines into one logical source
>   line. This is a single-pass operation, a line ending in two
>   backslashes followed by an empty line does not combine three lines
>   into one). If a universal character name (\uXXX) is formed on this
>   phase, the behavior is undefined.
>  2) If a non-empty source file does
>   not end with a newline character after this step (whether it had no
>   newline originally, or it ended with a backslash) the behavior is
>   undefined (until C++11) a terminating newline character is added
>   (since C++11)

If your current line is a single line comment, following line would be digested in continuation as a comment.

Answer (score 7):

http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/general/33653/

You can add the "\" anywhere in the code and newline will be ignored.

As a better reference the 2.2 paragraph of the standard:

> Each instance of a backslash character () immediately followed by a new-line 
>   character is deleted, splicing physical source lines to
>   form logical source lines. Only the last backslash on any physical
>   source line shall be eligible for being part of such a splice. If, as
>   a result, a character sequence that matches the syntax of a
>   universal-character-name is produced, the behavior is undefined. A
>   source file that is not empty and that does not end in a new-line
>   character, or that ends in a new-line character immediately preceded
>   by a backslash character before any such splicing takes place, shall
>   be processed as if an additional new-line character were appended to
>   the file.

This is not clear regarding what happens if the last character in the
file is a backslash. In such a case, presumably the result of adding
the newline should not be a line splice but rather a backslash
preprocessing-token (that will be diagnosed as an invalid token in
phase 7), but that should be spelled out.

Comment: The reference you cite isn't very good, and doesn't really explain what is happening from the standard point of view.

Comment: Attached the standard paragraph as the better reference as well, but I can see that others already did it.

Comment: "a backslash preprocessing-token (that will be diagnosed as an invalid token in phase 7)" -- no, a preprocessing token cannot produce a diagnostic if it appears as part of a comment that is removed before phase 7. A trailing backslash is harmless (and isn't a separate preprocessing token).

Answer (score 5):

As per [Working Draft, Standard for Programming
Language C++](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2005/n1905.pdf), Chapter 2 Lexical conventions, 2.1 - 2) :

> Each instance of a new-line character and an immediately preceding
>   backslash character a backslash character () immediately followed by
>   a new-line character is deleted, splicing physical source lines to
>   form logical source lines. Only the last backslash on any physical
>   source line shall be eligible for being part of such a splice.

This is also applicable to comments and this is still part of the final version.

Comment: The page cited doesn't answer his question (and really isn't very useful in general).

Answer (score -6):

It's in the C++ Standard, like everything about the C++ language. You can download a draft of the C++ Standard for free (for almost everybody except people involved in the design of the C++ language and compiler writers the draft is good enough), just google for "C++ Standard Draft".

Comment: It is not answering the question. The reason OP added question is he couldn't find the information in the standard.

Comment: @cerkiewny, that's an assumption. Nowhere in the post does it explicitly say they couldn't find the answer. They, perhaps, don't care to look; that's not clear.

Comment: Take a look at this post: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/15650/ban-lmgtfy-let-me-google-that-for-you-links it explains why your approach of answering the question shouldn't really be used.

Comment: ...however, this is not an answer to the question. op specifically asked for the location *in* the standard. It's not as if searching the standard for a clarification is always willy-nilly.