# Multiline preprocessor macro with trailing comments

Tags: c++, c, gcc, g++, c-preprocessor

I want to define the following ordinary looking macro:

```
#define MY_ENUM enum MyEnum{ \
    myVal0, \ //Describes this situation
    myVal2  \ //Describes that situation
}
```

To my surprise this doesn't work due to `error: stray ‘\’ in program`. Even some whitespace after the backslash results in `warning: backslash and newline separated by space`. As [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10419556/1525238) points out, the backslash must be the last character on the line. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25157708/1525238) points out that line splicing occurs before comments are processed. The reason why this order was chosen makes absolutely no sense to me; the only reason I can imagine this could be done is to allow multiline comments like the following:

```
//This is a comment which \
follows in the next line
```

Which looks extremely dangerous as such a thing could just eat up whatever code is on the next line when attempted. The reverse order, i.e replace each comment with single whitespace before splicing lines sounds like a much more sensible choice to me. Can someone explain why this choice was made?

I can work around my original problem with the following:

```
#define MY_ENUM enum MyEnum{ \
    myVal1, /*Describes this situation*/ \
    myVal2  /*Describes that situation*/ \
}
```

My purpose when doing this awkward enum macro definition is that this macro must be shared between c++ (where it absolutely must be a class member due to Qt) and c. Defining a macro such as this looks like the only solution to me but the above workaround looks ugly and I absolutely don't want to leave enums uncommented. Am I approaching this problem wrong?

Comment: Pardon my naivete, but why do you need an enum macro?  I would place the enum definition into a header file and include the header file.

Comment: You've described the problem you ran into, and you've described the solution. Use `/*...*/` comments.

Comment: It does sound like you're asking if you can write C code using non-C syntax because it'd look nicer... which is a little odd.

Comment: Notice, that even if comments were recognized before splicing, your code will still not work: comments are replaced with a space, so your `\` wouldn't be last character anyway.

Comment: "... splicing occurs before comments are processed.  This order makes absolutely no sense to me;"  --> Its is called a **pre**-processor after all for it processes input _before_ evaluating it the C C++ code.

Comment: The reason for the enum macro: To be used in both c++ as a *member* enum and also in c. That's why I'm not able to define them regularly in a header and include in both places. I would like better solutions though.

Comment: @chux in this sense, comments are part of c code that must not be interpreted by the preprocessor. This makes no sense to me either, they are not part of code and they are not to be *interpreted* by anything other than a human. Am I thinking wrong?

Comment: Comments _are_ part of the C code.  They act as white-spaces.  Example:`-/*abc*/-a` is the same as code `- -a`, not `--a`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that the C preprocessor just adds another line ending character when the `\` is hit and continued.

Within `//` comments you can't do that. The `\` character isn't accepted to continue the comment (it's supposed to appear as a single line anyway).

---

The solution is—as you found out yourself—to use the `/* */` comment style.

Comment: The line splicing happens first, putting the whole macro definition including the comments on one line... so the first `//` comments out the remainder of the macro definition.  With the `/* */` comments, the comment can be closed before the end of the line, which is why that style still works.

Answer (score 1):

To understand this phenomenon, you may to refer into the C standard (I believe that C++ is similar to C in that manner). In particular it's in *translation phases* section (C11 draft §5.1.1.2).

The preprocessor is obligated to behave just like as the phases are executed in the top-down order (i.e. step 3 is executed after step 2 has finished completely etc.).

Basically, the `//` and `/* ... */` comments are recognized in phase three, that is performed *after* the trailing `\` handling (i.e. phase two), meaning that it is agnostic to them. In other words, it treats them just like an ordinary source text with no special meaning.

> 2. Each instance of a backslash character (\) immediately followed by a new-line character is deleted, splicing physical source lines to
>      form logical source lines. Only the last backslash on any physical
>      source line shall be eligible for being part of such a splice.
> 3. The source file is decomposed into preprocessing tokens<sup>7)</sup> and sequences of white-space characters (including comments). A source file shall not end in a partial preprocessing token or in a partial comment.Each comment is replaced by one space character. New-line characters are retained. Whether each nonempty sequence of white-space
>      characters other than new-line is retained or replaced by one space
>      character is implementation-defined.

Comment: I modifie the question text to clarify that I already know that this is the case (check the references I gave in the question), what I don't understand is why this choice was made.